# Rotate object around another object

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I drew two rectangles in my scene, and now I'm trying to rotate one rectangle around the other.

When I press the "Left key" my first rectangle moves in direction to the other, but I don't have the effect of rotate because it is only moving in a straight line in direction of the other rectangle.

How do I change the Z direction of the first rectangle?

tl;dr: It's like a solar system, but I don't understand how can I have the depth effect.

I'm using GLUT and OpenGL.

EDIT: More Info:

This is my current code (function that shows the scene):

```
void RenderScene(void){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 

    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(-70.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRectf(-25.0f, 25.0f, 25.0f, -25.0f); 
    glPopMatrix();

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(xCor, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRectf(-25.0f, 25.0f, 25.0f, -25.0f);
    glPopMatrix();

    glFlush(); 
}
```

And a image to help:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have some code to display?

Comment: What does it mean to change the Z direction? Can you draw some pictures of what are you trying to do?

Comment: I think he means the normal, i.e. rotating the rectangle.

Comment: Guys, I added more info so you can understand my doubt.

Comment: Seriously, i think you should avoid use the fixed function pipeline. Use Vertex-Buffers, Shaders,.... and if you do it you also need to use matrices for you math and this will solve your problem really quick.

Answer (score 1):

Please enable depth test to hide objects beyond other objects.
Give a high value z vaue for the far object.

```
glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT |GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glPushMatrix();

glTranslatef(-70.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRectf(-25.0f, 25.0f, 25.0f, -25.0f); 
glPopMatrix();

glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(xCor, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRectf(-25.0f, 25.0f, 25.0f, -26.0f); // Z value of behind object is set far from eye
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Ok, the GL_DEPTH_TEST was the first thing I need, but I still dont understand how do I make the rectangle go far away in the scene (when it is behind the red rectangle) and near the scene when its completing the circle around the red one.

Comment: Change projection to perspective. Glperspective or glfrustum will help you. Then far z objects become smaller comparing to near objects.

Comment: gluPerspective seems to fit my problem, now I need to understand it. If I use the command gluPerspective(45, fAspect, -50.0, 400); I cant see any of the objects... why?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is moderately complicated.

The only way I know to locate rectangles in 3-space is to build them using glVertex3f() like this:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);  
    glVertex3f(x0, y0, z0);  
    glVertex3f(x1, y1, z1);
    glVertex3f(x2, y2, z2);  
    glVertex3f(x3, y3, z3);  
glEnd();
```

Your "solar system" will have to be located in screen coordinates: X->left/right, Y->up/down, Z->into/out of screen. To create the effect of orbiting, you'll have to recalculate all four X and Z for each movement increment.

I also suggest using gluLookAt() if you want to see a different view.

The man page for glPerspective() says that zNear is always positive but you've given it a negative number. I'd leave that line commented out until I saw some orbiting.

HTH.

Comment: In fact, what I'm trying to do is a scene where objects rotate around one in the center. I'm using rectangles just because the code is cleaner than when I use objects and its textures